# Are floats a secure alternative to generating an un-biased random number

Tags: algorithm, random

I have always generated un-biased random numbers by throwing away any numbers in the biased range. Similar to this

```
int biasCount = MAX_INT % max
int maxSafeNumber = MAX_INT - biasCount;
int generatedNumber = 0;

do 
{
   generatedNumber = GenerateNumber();

} while (generatedNumber > maxSafeNumber)

return generatedNumber % max;
```

Today a friend showed me how he generated random numbers by converting the generated number into a float, then multiplying that against the max.

```
float percent = generatedNumber / (float)MAX_INT; 
return (int)(percent * max);
```

This seems to solve the bias issue by not having to use a modulus in the first place. It also looks simple and fast. **Is there any reason why the float approach would not be as secure (unbiased) as the first one?**

Comment: Why do you think it might nit be *secure*?

Comment: The best way is to use a ranged random provided by your language. For example, C++ provides `<random>` that includes such functionality.

Comment: "Secure" probably is not the term you're looking for.  Just say "unbiased".

Comment: @Raedwald I don't see a flaw in it, but that doesn't mean there isn't one and it can't hurt to check especially when it comes to security. jamesdlin You're right, I'll update the verbage for that.

Comment: You friend's algorithm is biased. Let MAX_INT=3, max=2, how can you evenly distribute 3 apples into 2 baskets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The float method with a floor (i.e. your cast) introduces a bias
  against the largest value in your range.

  In order to return `max`, `generatedNumber == MAX_INT` must be true.
  So `max` has probability `1/MAX_INT`, while every other number in the
  range has probability `max/MAX_INT`
- As Henry points out, there's also the issue of aliasing if `MAX_INT`
  is not a multiple of `max`. This makes some values in the range more
  likely than others. The larger the difference between `max` and `MAX_INT` the smaller this bias is.

(Assuming you get, and want, a uniform distribution.)

This presentation by Stephan T. Lavavej from GoingNative 2013 goes over a lot of common fallacies with random numbers, including these range schemes. It's C++ centric in the implementations, but all the concepts carry over to any language:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 1):

The float method may not generate uniformly distributed output numbers even when the input numbers are uniformly distributed. To see where it breaks down do some examples with small numbers e.g. max = 6, MAX_INT = 8

it gets better when MAX_INT is large, but it is almost never perfect.